# How can be the keys of a Map be treated equal if they have similar properties but in different order?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have a Pair class and -

```
Map<Pair<String, String>, String> map = new HashMap<Pair<String, String>, String>();
map.put(new Pair("name1", "address1"), "Young");
map.put(new Pair("name2", "address2"), "Old");
.
.
. and so on.
```

Now I have a requirement where I have to treat two pairs as equal where

```
pair1 = new Pair("name1", "address1");
pair2 = new Pair("address1", "name1");
```

Note that `pair2` in not as a key in the map but `pair1` is. So that when I do

```
map.get(pair1);
map.get(pair2);
```

gives me same result as `"Young"`;

What additional things should I do to achieve it?

Comment: override .equals() and hashcode() in pair class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to override `equals()` and `hashcode()` in the Pair class.
Also refer these https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265637/869488

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609/869488 (check the 'Also remember' heading of these answer)

Answer (score 1):

Override `hashCode()` and `equals()` method in `Pair` class so that,

```
pair1 = new Pair("name1", "address1");
pair2 = new Pair("address1", "name1");
```

will be in same hash bucket in a hashmap. When you do correctly override the `hashCode()` method to ensure that equal objects get equal hash codes, the hashmap is able to find the two equal objects and place them in the same hash bucket.